# Interesting sequence question

Tags: number-theory, recreational-mathematics

I saw a puzzle the other day and it was as follows:

```
Find the next number in the sequence: 1 11 21 1211 111221 312211 ...
```

If anyone wants to have a go at the puzzle I'll put the solution in a spoiler

> Next number: 13112221 - 1 three, 1 one, 2 twos, 2 ones

My question is - what mathematical machinery is there to analyse a sequence like this? I can see that $2^n$ is an upper bound for the number of digits (if all digits in the previous number are different), but I'm wondering if one could do better, or get a lower bound as well, or maybe analyse it from a completely different direction.

I wrote a simple python script to calculate the sequence as follows (note: the actual value can get very big - and you can remove it from the array)

```
import math

def next_number(num):
  num = list(str(num))
  position = -2
  output = []
  prev_char = None # anything other than a number
  for char in num:
    if char == prev_char:
      output[position] += 1
    else:
      output += [1, int(char)]
      position += 2
      prev_char = char
  output = [str(i) for i in output]
  return int(''.join(output))

def calculate_sequence(count):
  num = 1
  ans = []
  for count in xrange(count):
    length = math.floor(math.log10(num)) + 1
    ans.append([count+1, length, num])
    num = next_number(num)
  return ans
```

Comment: Wikipedia reference: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Look-and-say_sequence

Comment: For one thing, it's very easy to prove that no digit apart from 1,2 and 3 will occur in the sequence.

Comment: Well that's boring! It's already been studied!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As complexist said, there's [a wikipedia article about it](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Look-and-say_sequence) which links to some good sources with explanations of the statements of key theorems (including the famous [Cosmological Theorem](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/CosmologicalTheorem.html), which says that there is a global bound after which every look-and-say sequence breaks up into a bunch of predictable pieces) whose original proofs have been lost.

[Litherland](https://www.math.lsu.edu/~lither/jhc/) and [Ekhad and Zeilberger](http://www.math.rutgers.edu/~zeilberg/mamarim/mamarimhtml/horton.html) both have computerized proofs of things approaching [Conway's original claims](http://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-1-4612-4808-8_53), but they don't achieve the bounds Conway claimed, and these proofs are difficult to verify.

More recently, Kevin Watkins at CMU wrote [a paper](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~kw/pubs/conway.pdf) and [slides](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~kw/pubs/conwayslides.pdf) explaining how you could use Haskell and words to produce an explicitly human-understandable computer-aided proof of the main theorems (which still doesn't yield the originally claimed bounds).

There has also been [a tidy blog post by Nathaniel Johnston explaining the derivation of the asymptotic growth rate](http://www.nathanieljohnston.com/2010/10/a-derivation-of-conways-degree-71-look-and-say-polynomial/).